# How to display image in full page with device size width

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working within mvc,
I want to display Image on website which is in full size on page but width of image is always equal to width of browser page

Comment: More Negative is lesson to write a clear question.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Why not pose the question in terms of the specific problem you see on the screen with a browser.  Is it that you have tall narrow pictures that are not expanded out so the width matches the browser window width?

Comment: yes.. actually i have images of pdf files and hence user can read that images easily....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style the image with `max-width: 100%`.

Comment: and  if i want to display that image on another tab of browser  by clicking on button then......????

Comment: If you're talking about an alink styled as a button, then you'd set the href of the link to the image URL and set the target to "_blank".

Comment: great i got it, and i make changes that, i am using image click event to open new window, and after clicking i got new window , but main image also changing its size... thenn how can i solve this